# How to up-sample a binary sequence from 1020 samples to 2000 samples

Tags: algorithm, gps, signal-processing, interpolation, resampling

I have a random binary sequence (PRBS) of length say 1020 and want to up-sample this to 2000 points. I am looking to implement this is in an FPGA and have been looking at polyphase filters which seem overly complex for my case. Is this the way forward or is there a simpler way I can implement this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Basically I have generated a pseudo-random binary sequence and will use this to correlate with an incoming signal but i need this sequence to match it's data rate with that of the incoming signal samples which are always at a higher rate. Think spread-spectrum/GPS. Just wondering what the best way to go about this may be.

Comment: More details would be nice.

Comment: unlike real continuous "physical" signal you can not up/down sample pseudo-random binary signal and expect the same probabilistic/statistic parameters. The best way is to generate the sequence in target resolution/frequency directly. But essentially your question is very vague and without knowing what exactly you are doing and for what purpose we can only guess...

Comment: Apologies for the poor wording and/or lack of detail. Lets say I have generated the PRN to be used to de-spread a GPS signal at the receiver. I need the sample rate of the generated PRN to match the sampled signal incoming from the ADC. So essentially I will be oversampling the PRN. Your suggestion to generate at the target frequency is the logical way, its just I want to know what my options are in the case I want to generate and then up-sample the signal.

Comment: Spread spectrum usually defines an integer spreading factor. Each symbol of the input sequence is then simply repeated as many times as the spreading factor (before being multiplied by the pseudo-random spreading sequence). Interpolation of a binary sequence is unlikely going to yield anything useful.

Comment: Can't you just use the same pseudo-random generation algorithm to generate more data points, and tack them on to the end?

Comment: You could try dsp.stackexchange.com if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I finally figured it out after 3 restless nights. I was making my problem too complex! I just have to use the integer part of a fixed point number to index the destination array which allows me to spread out the 1020 bits over 2000 bits. Easily doable on an FPGA and no multiplies necessary!